# Simple embedded database with spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, in-memory-database

How to setup a simple embedded database in a spring(data)+maven project?

I need to develop a simple graphical application that read some data files and display pretty stuff about it interactively. The data is very repetitive with a little hierarchical structure. However I still don't know how I will need to access it.

For these reasons, I want to store it in a database so that I can later use DB query to access the data with query filter. (it also seems a good idea to develop a persistent layer)

Because it is for a little application, I want to use an *in-memory* DB.

I am quite new to java (using proper dev framework) and database. But I worked on a project using spring, spring-data, JPA, etc... I did not really understand how it worked internally and would not be able to setup it up, but I found it very practical.

Now, I found lots of docs and tutorial on internet about that, but I didn't understand enough to know how to adapt them to my need. What (I think) I want is:

- to use maven+spring
- spring data (I guess) to use Entity, JpaRepository and Autowired stuff
- an independent program, thus starting from a Application.main method
- as little and simple dependencies as possible
- an embedded DB (+fast+light if possible)
- genericity is nice

What I fill to be lost with are:

- where should I put what properties/xml-declaration
- how are all the dependencies working together (spring, spring-data, h2, hsqldb, ...)

I found this project https://github.com/wrpinheiro/spring-jpa-embedded-db that looks to fit, but:

- there are way too many dependencies that (I think) I don't need, thus don't want
- I don't know how to start a program with it
- I don't get the `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` thing
- nor the `javax.inject.Inject`

Comment: You could have a look at http://db.apache.org/derby/

Comment: good info, but it seems it should still be installed on execution machines (the classpath must be set). Maybe I did not understand what mean "embedded"...

Comment: I use derby for unitTesting. But you probably can create a runnable jar-with-dependencies, and get derby embedded. The classpath is therefore declared in the jar Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you look at this project you can start building what you need
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/#initial

Its maven (or gradle), has enbeded db, spring-jpa and runs as a jar that starts its own tomcat server (you can change it into a war build if you want)

Also you can use this service(?) that spring provides to create the starting build for your project:
http://start.spring.io

You provide them with what you want to build and then the code and required files are generated :D
Pretty neat.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is the constructed jar stand-alone runnable?  2) Is is possible to remove the "parent" dependency?

Comment: The start.sping.io is pretty cool, but what dependencies/config should I put?

Comment: I did some test (needed to remove the rest stuff, some problem with maven version it seems) but it worked. I did still didn't try to generate jar

Comment: You run the "mcn clean package" and the .jar should be generated.

Comment: "mvn* clean package" I meant :)

Comment: alright. I still did not manage it but I left that aside for now. In term of dev, it was more efficient to implement my own ad-hoc datastructure. Hopefully, I'll later find time to finish it, and maybe share the code on github.